# Were the Content-Version and Derived-From HTTP headers deprecated?

Tags: http, http-headers, conditional-statements

The [`Content-Version`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-19.6.2.2) and [`Derived-From`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-19.6.2.3) were defined in [RFC 2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-19.6.2.3).

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) says:

> The `Alternates`, `Content-Version`, `Derived-From`, `Link`, `URI`, `Public` and `Content-Base` header fields were defined in previous versions of this specification, but not commonly implemented. [...]

The newer versions (if you follow the links in the *Obsolete by*, *Updated by* at the top of those RFCs) do not mention anything about those two headers. However, they mention the [`If-Match`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1).

It looks like it would be very easy to implement the `Content-Version` and `Derived-From` headers, but if newer apps are expected to use the `ETag` and `If-Match` instead, should I stick with those only?

Comment: Why would you want to implement something that has been replaced by something else around 20 years ago?

Comment: @JulianReschke, that's kind of my question. Was it really deprecated?

Comment: Well, they were removed and replaced by something else. Does it really matter whether somebody said "deprecated"? FWIW, what's relevant is the IANA registry, and that (currently) does not have a "deprecated" status anyway.

Comment: @JulianReschke What were they replaced by? I'm looking at the RFCs and trying to trace where they went. Thanks!

Comment: Which of these specifically? Some may have replacements, some may have been abandoned. Is there any practical value here except for researching spec history?